# Angular unit test - changes are not detected on button click

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm testing this method which is triggered on submit button click

```
  addItem(): void{
    console.log("Adding Item")
    this.newItem.id= "100"
    this.newItem.name ="Shampoo"
 }
```

I want to trigger this method from a unit test on submit button click. However I don't think it's triggering, because the expected values '100' and 'Shampoo' are ''. So the assertion fails

**Unit Test class**

```
let store: MockStore<AppState>;
let fixture :ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
let component: AppComponent;

const initialState = { 
  shopping:{
    list: [],
    loading: false,
    error: undefined
  }, 
  loggedIn: false };

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule ,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule    
      ],
      providers:[
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents().then(()=>{

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });


  fit('should add item on button click', () => {

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.newItem.id).toEqual('');
    expect(component.newItem.name).toEqual('');
    //debugger;
    const btn:DebugElement =fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#addBtn'))
    btn.triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit',null);
    expect(component.newItem.id).toEqual('100');
    expect(component.newItem.name).toEqual('Shampoo');
  });
});
```

Here is my html class

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="addItem()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem.name" placeholder="Item" name="itemName"/>
    <button type="submit" id="addBtn">+Add</button>
  </form>
```

What am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Change the test to this:

```
  fit('should add item on button click', async() => { // add async here because some aspects 
// Angular forms are asynchronous

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.newItem.id).toEqual('');
    expect(component.newItem.name).toEqual('');
    //debugger; grab the nativeElement (HTMLElement) by adding .nativeElement towards the end of the line
    const btn = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#addBtn')).nativeElement;
    btn.click(); // click the button
    await fixture.whenStable(); // wait until form promises have completed, this could be not needed.
    expect(component.newItem.id).toEqual('100');
    expect(component.newItem.name).toEqual('Shampoo');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I have to trigger form submit, not button click

```
fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form')).triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
```